# Were Men aware that Aragorn was being raised amongst the Elves?

Tags: tolkiens-legendarium, the-lord-of-the-rings

I have been told that Aragorn was taken and raised amongst the Elves in one of my [previous questions](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/188614/68872).

Was there anyone who was aware of this? If so since he is the heir of Isildur did anyone search for him?

When people were aware of him and his legacy, were there any human supporters who agreed to his right to get the throne and willing to fight for him?

Comment: I've removed your last question as it made the post opinion based. Everything else can be answered in a reasonably related manner.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

## Yes people were aware of him and he had support

The people of the Dunedain were indeed aware of his fostering in Rivendell as it was tradition for their Chieftains to be fostered there (Elrond did not *take* Aragorn but provided the traditional service of raising the future Cheiftain, having been aware of their lineage stretching back to his own brother, Elros), where the heirlooms of Isildur were kept:

> Arahael his son was fostered in Rivendell, **and so were all the sons of the chieftains after him**; and there also were kept the heirlooms of their house: the ring of Barahir, the shards of Narsil, the star of Elendil, and the sceptre of Annúminas.
> <sub>The Return of the King - Book 7, Appendix A: (iii) Eriador, Arnor, and the Heirs of Isildur</sub>

The Gondorians however, were unaware of the happenings in the North, and as far as the books lead us to believe were unaware of the Heirs of Isildur still existing. (As covered in [this Q&A](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/106757/68872))

Had Aragorn chosen to announce his kingship after coming of age, he would've had support from the Dunedain as he was the Chieftain of that people. However, as covered in [this Q&A](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/139720/68872), an earlier return by Aragorn would've led to the rejection from the people of Gondor, the largest population of Men and the most powerful, and as such he would've been cast aside, as Arvedui had been before him.

Comment: Since they weren't given fake names or raised in ignorance of their identities I don't think it's logical to use their example for the specific case of Aragorn.

Answer (score 1):

Elrond had long been a friend to the Dúnedain of Arnor who became the Rangers. Their chiefs were direct descendants of Isildur. Aragorn's father, Arathorn, was killed fighting orcs when Aragorn was just two years old. In order to safeguard the line of Isildur, Elrond offered sanctuary to the infant Aragorn and his mother Gilraen. He was given a fake name (Estel) and not informed of his true identity until he came of age.

We can speculate that the most senior Rangers would have probably known what had happened to their future chief but they would have dissuaded anyone seeking him or even discussing his whereabouts.

Comment: Do you have any evidence/quotes to back this up?

Comment: I don't believe there is any evidence from the books on how the Rangers, or any other humans, reacted to Aragorn's fostering at Rivendell aged two. That's why I said "We can speculate..." OP seemed to suggest Aragorn had been spirited away by Elrond and people might be looking for him which was obviously not the case.